# Names for each point in scatter3, Matlab.

Tags: matlab, scatter3d

I have been trying to name each point in space for scatter3 plot in matlab, and came up with this code.

```
x = [-30;-50;-40;-60;-60;-60;-30;30;60;60;60;40;50;30];
y = [50;30;30;0;20;-60;-80;-80;-60;20;0;30;30;50];
z = [30;0;40;30;0;0;10;10;0;0;30;40;0;30];

for a = 1:14

    location{1} = sprintf('AF3');
    location{2} = sprintf('F7');
    location{3} = sprintf('F3');
    location{4} = sprintf('FC5');
    location{5} = sprintf('T7');
    location{6} = sprintf('P7');
    location{7} = sprintf('O1');
    location{8} = sprintf('O2');
    location{9} = sprintf('P8');
    location{10} = sprintf('T8');
    location{11} = sprintf('FC6');
    location{12} = sprintf('F4');
    location{13} = sprintf('F8');
    location{14} = sprintf('AF4');
    n = location{k};
    s=strread(sprintf(n),...
              '%s','delimiter','');
end

scatter3(-x,-y,-z);
text(-(x+.1),-(y-.5),-z,s,...
     'color',[1,0,0]);
view(115,18)
```

but when i plot it i get all the points a F7.

I am new to Matlab, can any one help me with this.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, better answers are always welcome.

```
for a = 1:14
    n = location{a};
    location{1} = sprintf('AF3');
    location{2} = sprintf('F7');
    location{3} = sprintf('F3');
    location{4} = sprintf('FC5');
    location{5} = sprintf('T7');
    location{6} = sprintf('P7');
    location{7} = sprintf('O1');
    location{8} = sprintf('O2');
    location{9} = sprintf('P8');
    location{10} = sprintf('T8');
    location{11} = sprintf('FC6');
    location{12} = sprintf('F4');
    location{13} = sprintf('F8');
    location{14} = sprintf('AF4');
    s(a)=strread(sprintf(n),'%s','delimiter','');
end


% the plot
     scatter3(-x,-y,-z); % <- NOT <plot3>
     text(-(x+.1),-(y-.5),-z,s,...
         'color',[1,0,0]);
     view(115,18)
```